# New Rails app Postgres won't install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I just started a Rails 4 app from scratch with the intention to use Postgres. I went and changed the database.yml file to the following:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: personalapi_dev
  pool: 5
  username: nickoneill
  password:
  host: localhost  

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test: &test
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: personalapi_test
  pool: 5
  username: nickoneill
  password:
  host: localhost
```

Yet when I run `rake db:create` it gives me the following error:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::PG
/Users/nickoneill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@personalapi/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:562:in `active?'
/Users/nickoneill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@personalapi/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:360:in `verify!'
/Users/nickoneill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@personalapi/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:458:in `block in checkout_and_verify'
/Users/nickoneill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@personalapi/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1536634998624253346__checkout__callbacks'
/Users/nickoneill/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@personalapi/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
```

I've tried everything from upgrading the Postgres gem, making sure Postgres is running, etc, yet not sure why it's not working. I have other rails apps (including Rails 4) on my computer that run just fine yet this new one won't work. Any ideas?

**Update**

Here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.0.0"

# gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'addressable'

#
# Error handling
#
gem "sentry-raven" #, :git => "https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby.git"

#
# Sidekiq gems
#
gem 'sidekiq' , '2.5.4'
gem 'redis' , '~> 3.0'
gem 'unicorn' , '~> 4.5'

# For sidekiq interface
#gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
gem 'sinatra', '>= 1.3.0', :require => nil

# json parsing
gem 'oj' , '2.0.1'

# templates
gem 'haml'

# file storage
# gem "paperclip", "~> 3.1"
# gem 'aws-sdk', '1.8.0'

# Use postgres as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development , :test do
    gem "better_errors"
    gem 'fakeweb'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.12.2'
    gem 'shoulda-matchers'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
end

group :test do 
    #gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.3.0"
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails' , '~> 4.0'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'guard-spork'
    gem 'spork'
    gem "launchy"
    gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1'
    gem 'faker'
    gem 'annotate'
    gem 'simplecov'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'growl'
    gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1'
end
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: @PinnyM I've updated it with the gemfile

Comment: The reference to `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::PG` is somewhat odd - the line in question (562) calls `PGError`.  The line above that (561) references `PG`. Can you try reinstalling the activerecord gem?  Also, what version of the 'pg' gem are you actually using in your bundle?

Comment: I looked at the Gemfile.lock and found it it hadn't updated to the latest pg gem. By explicitly calling `gem 'pg', '0.15.1'` in the gemfile and rebuilding the gemfile.lock it fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my experience updating the Gemfile to gem 'pg', '0.15.1' solved the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem on Heroku. `0.15.1` solved it. Thank you!